# Error 1004 deleting a range target of Worksheet_Change

Tags: excel, vba

I have this sub on one of my page, I want that when the user changes one of the cells in B2:B10, the date appears in the column A on the same line :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B10")) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = Date
End If

End Sub
```

It works well, but if I select the range A2:B10 and I press Delete I have a 1004 Run Time Error. Do you know why and how I could avoid that ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When selecting a range from A2 to B10, the intersect in your if is true, but when using Target.Offset(0, -1) you are trying to address a range that is to the left of column A. Because column A is the first one, this obviously leads to an error.

So try to check if the `Target.Column` is bigger than 1:

```
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B10")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Column > 1 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False 'Prevents the Event from firing again when changing a value.
        Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = Date
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End If
```

Also, without disabling the Events, changing a value inside the Change Event will trigger it again leading to a loop.

Comment: Perfect it works, thanks ! Is there a way to have strict intersection ? If the target is not exactly B2:B10, then intersect is false ?

Comment: This would check if the target is exactly B2:B10:
`If Target.Address(False, False) = "B2:B10" Then`